# Does TextField fireDoneEvent() to call stopEditing() in order to close the virtual keyyboard?

Tags: textfield, codenameone

I can close the virtualkeyboard from a button by calling textField.stopEditing. However, I would have expecting setting a DoneListener to close the virtualkeyboard as well when "Search" or "Go" is pressed.

The DoneListener does fire and the code is executed, but the virtualkeyboard remains open. I've tried adding a stopEditing to the DoneListerer, even placing stopEditing callSerially.

Comment: This should work. What else are you doing within the done listener? Normally done automatically folds the keyboard so if this fails something else is going on in the text field.

Comment: I post a ConnectionRequest to the NetworkManager and process the response using the callSerially to update another TextField. The exact same code is executed by the button, the difference is that the button calls the textField.stopEditing method.

Comment: Did you try wrapping the whole connection request call in a call serially.

Comment: Yes. For the time being I'm going not use any special virtualKeyboard buttons and rely on the external button.

Comment: In which platform is this happening?

Comment: Android 6.0, Android 4.04, ios7.1.2; it may still be something that I'm doing else where in a background thread

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just tried this on my Android OPO device and it worked as expected. The second field did nothing but the first folded the keyboard like a champ:

```
Form hi = new Form("TextTest", BoxLayout.y());
TextField other = new TextField("");
TextField ttt = new TextField("");
hi.add(ttt).add(other);
ttt.setDoneListener(e -> {
    hi.add(ttt.getText());
    hi.getContentPane().animateLayout(200);
});
hi.show();
```

[image]

Comment: I'm guessing that an EDT violation would cause this problem. In a background thread I am doing some processing with ImageIO.getImageIO().save(input, output, ImageIO.FORMAT_JPEG, width, height, QUALITY);

Comment: Today's update  fixed the ios7 for me, but not the Android

Comment: We'll need a test case for that, I know Steve is working on an issue in text field but I'm unsure if it's the same issue as the symptoms are different.

Comment: I'm getting an EDT violation in a background thread at priority 1. 
  ByteArrayInputStream input = new ByteArrayInputStream(data);
  ByteArrayOutputStream output = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
-> ImageIO.getImageIO().save(input, output, ImageIO.FORMAT_JPEG, width, height, QUALITY);
  data = output.toByteArray();
Replaced with 
-> Image image = EncodedImage.create(data).scaled(width, height);
  data = EncodedImage.createFromImage(image, true).getImageData();
Still get an EDT.
EncodedImage relies on ImageIO. ImageIO relies on Display. Can the cache in ImageIO  be a problem?

Comment: An EDT violation could cause weird issues but you seem to be describing something quite different.

Comment: Is there something about ImageIO that can only be run from the EDT?

Comment: No. The EDT violation detection code is overzealous. We prefer having false positives over missing a potential problem.